# Select with count by months

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, count, case

I have Pickup table and trying to write a report which will show me how many pickups were in each month in a year.
It should looks like this 
[image]

I so far  i have this

```
  SELECT
DATEPART(MONTH, PickupDate)as 'Month',
count (CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, PickupDate) = 2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)as 'Pickups'
,count (CASE WHEN CategCode  = 'NB' and DATEPART(YEAR, PickupDate) = 2012  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as 'Newborn'
FROM dbo.Pickup 
where DATEPART(YEAR, PickupDate) = 2012
group by DATEPART(MONTH, PickupDate)

WITH ROLLUP
```

I cannot figure out how to calculate Newborn column, any ideas?
My query  so far calculate not right it just count all pickup from pickup table.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `COUNT` to `SUM` or change the `ELSE 0` to `ELSE NULL`.

`COUNT(0,1,0)` = 3, `SUM(0, 1, 0)` = 1, `COUNT(NULL,1,NULL)` = 1

If I may offer another hint, try to rewrite the query using date comparisons rather than the DATEPART function - the use of this function will prevent the optimizer from utilizing indexes. A calendar table is the way to go here.

Comment: didn't get how and where to use comparisons

Comment: Ask another question and I'll give you the answer

Comment: give me a few minutes to finish this query